# JSON consumption in python django

Tags: python, json, django, django-templates, django-rest-framework

This is the json output I get -

```
{
"count": 2,
"next": null,
"previous": null,
"check": [
    {
        "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/app_name/cities/1/persons/?format=json",
        "id": 1,
        "name": "City1"
    },
    {
        "url": "http://127.0.0.1:8000/app_name/cities/2/persons/?format=json",
        "id": 2,
        "name": "City2"
    }
]
}
```

I am using the view given below-

```
def get_name(request):
data = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/app_name/cities/?format=json')
context = RequestContext(request, {
    'cities': data.check,
})
return render_to_response('template', context)
```

To be able to use this data in my template like so -

`template.html`

```
{% block names %}
{% for city in cities %}
<a href="{% url 'next_view_name' city.id %}"><p>{{city.name}}</p></a>
{% endfor %}
{% endblock %}
```

but, that gives me the following error - 
`'Response' object has no attribute 'check'`

What is the correct process of returning dictionary values of json data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to manipulate the response object - which is coming from requests. You need to cover it the json string it contains to an object first, before you can do anything else:

```
def get_name(request):
    data = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/app_name/cities/?format=json')
    data = data.json() # <-- convert the json to an object
    context = RequestContext(request, {
        'cities': data['check'],
    })
    return render_to_response('template', context)
```

Comment: I am still getting the same error `'dict' object has no attribute 'results'`

Comment: I'm sorry what I meant was I have tried that before posting here and I was getting that error and I don't know how to get all the values in `results`. Thanks.

Comment: I am getting this now `TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: What is the output of `data.text`?